# How can I remove the "Your vote was recorded." message in the polls?

Tags: polls

I need to delete the message "Your vote was recorded." when a user votes in a poll.

I tried comment the line containing `drupal_set_message(t('Your vote was recorded.'))` in the Poll module, but if I do this, the Poll Enhancements module doesn't work well.

What other way has Drupal 7 for deleting specific messages?

Comment: Editing a Drupal module is never suggested; if you update Drupal, you should editing the module all times.

Comment: yes, you are right.  What alternative is there for delete this message in the poll?  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The messages set with [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) are saved in `$_SESSION['messages'][$type]` as an array of strings (`$type` can be `"status"`, `"warning"`, or `"error"`). The message you see, is set in [poll_vote()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/function/poll_vote/7), which is the form submission handler used for processing a vote, used from [poll_view_voting()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/function/poll_view_voting/7), the form builder for the vote form.

In order to remove the show string you should:

- Implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to add a form submission handler that is executed after `poll_vote()`.
- Implement the form submission handler to remove the string added from `poll_vote()`.

Code similar to the following one should work.

```
function mymodule_form_poll_view_voting_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['vote']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_poll_view_submit';
}

function mymodule_poll_view_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($_SESSION['messages']['status']) && is_array($_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
    $messages = array_flip($_SESSION['messages']['status']);
    unset($messages[t('Your vote was recorded.')]);
    $_SESSION['messages']['status'] = $messages;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the drupal api, [drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7) by default clears out messages of the type selected.

The process is then to read the messages drupal_get_messages('error', TRUE) drupal_set_message() to put all the messages back on that you don't want to filter. This code can be found in the "Disable Messages module" which is more flexible.

The two implementation steps are i) add a function for managing the messages and ii) do the filtering:

```
function osdash_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['status_messages']['function'] = '_osdash_disable_status_messages';
}

function _osdash_disable_status_messages($display = NULL) {
  // Retrieve messages
  $messages = drupal_get_messages($display);
  if (!empty($messages['status'])) {
    foreach ($messages['status'] as $message_index => $message) {
      if ($message != 'Failed to find the list of invitees from the group.') {
        drupal_set_message($message, 'warning');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was posted 4 months ago and the original poster must have found a way, but for future users who might stumble upon this, a good and proper solution is the [Disable Messages module](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) . That way you won't need to hack core (no no no!), make a new module or modify your theme.